# Why does my laptop resume immediately after suspend?

Tags: 12.04, laptop, suspend, 32-bit

I seem to be having some problem with suspend mode. Every time I try to suspend my laptop, it just locks the screen. Or maybe it successfully suspends just to resume only an instant after. What could cause such a behaviour?

I'm running 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 with the 3.2.0-25 kernel on a HP dv5-1178er Pavilion laptop (Intel Core 2 Duo).

Here are the relevant log sections:

kern.log:

```
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.131171] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.141222] PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.141239] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.01 seconds) done.
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.156171] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.01 seconds) done.
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.172139] PM: Entering mem sleep
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.172169] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.172895] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.181767] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.251089] ene_ir 00:0a: wake-up capability enabled by ACPI
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.251115] i8042 aux 00:09: wake-up capability disabled by ACPI
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.251133] i8042 kbd 00:08: wake-up capability enabled by ACPI
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.251286] jmb38x_ms 0000:06:00.3: PCI INT A disabled
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.252491] sdhci-pci 0000:06:00.1: PCI INT A disabled
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.264130] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: PCI INT D disabled
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.264142] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: PCI INT B disabled
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.264325] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.1: PCI INT B disabled
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.288059] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: PCI INT A disabled
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.288097] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.3: PCI INT C disabled
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.288135] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: PCI INT A disabled
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.316051] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.7: PCI INT A disabled
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.316068] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.7: PCI INT D disabled
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.522872] PM: suspend of drv:sd dev:0:0:0:0 complete after 349.979 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.522901] PM: suspend of drv:scsi dev:target0:0:0 complete after 349.955 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.522927] PM: suspend of drv:scsi dev:host0 complete after 272.260 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.522969] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: BIOS update required for suspend/resume
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.522976] pci_legacy_suspend(): ahci_pci_device_suspend+0x0/0x80 returns -5
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.522981] pm_op(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x110 returns -5
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.522984] PM: suspend of drv:ahci dev:0000:00:1f.2 complete after 258.932 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.522987] PM: Device 0000:00:1f.2 failed to suspend async: error -5
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.576228] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: PCI INT A disabled
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.576270] ACPI handle has no context!
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.592136] PM: suspend of drv:snd_hda_intel dev:0000:00:1b.0 complete after 327.889 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.592206] PM: Some devices failed to suspend
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.592291] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.592298] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: setting latency timer to 64
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.592325] usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.592339] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.1: PCI INT B -> GSI 21 (level, low) -> IRQ 21
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.592345] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.1: setting latency timer to 64
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.592371] usb usb4: root hub lost power or was reset
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.592387] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.7: PCI INT D -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 19
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.592395] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.7: setting latency timer to 64
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.592843] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 20 (level, low) -> IRQ 20
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.592851] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: setting latency timer to 64
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.592854] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: PCI INT B -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 19
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.592863] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: setting latency timer to 64
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.592878] usb usb5: root hub lost power or was reset
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.592892] usb usb6: root hub lost power or was reset
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.592895] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: PCI INT D -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.592903] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: setting latency timer to 64
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.592906] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.3: PCI INT C -> GSI 18 (level, low) -> IRQ 18
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.592915] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.3: setting latency timer to 64
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.592930] usb usb7: root hub lost power or was reset
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.592946] usb usb8: root hub lost power or was reset
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.592949] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.7: PCI INT A -> GSI 20 (level, low) -> IRQ 20
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.592957] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.7: setting latency timer to 64
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.592963] pci 0000:00:1e.0: setting latency timer to 64
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.597106] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.608138] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: BAR 0: set to [mem 0xdf300000-0xdf303fff 64bit] (PCI address [0xdf300000-0xdf303fff])
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.608180] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: restoring config space at offset 0xf (was 0x100, writing 0x10b)
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.608233] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: restoring config space at offset 0x3 (was 0x0, writing 0x10)
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.608248] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: restoring config space at offset 0x1 (was 0x100000, writing 0x100002)
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.608299] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 22 (level, low) -> IRQ 22
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.608313] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: setting latency timer to 64
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.608420] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 50 for MSI/MSI-X
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.612095] firewire_ohci 0000:06:00.0: restoring config space at offset 0x1 (was 0x100000, writing 0x100006)
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.612181] sdhci-pci 0000:06:00.1: restoring config space at offset 0x1 (was 0x100003, writing 0x100007)
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.612211] sdhci-pci 0000:06:00.1: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.612225] sdhci-pci 0000:06:00.1: setting latency timer to 64
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.612296] jmb38x_ms 0000:06:00.3: restoring config space at offset 0x1 (was 0x100003, writing 0x100007)
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.612326] jmb38x_ms 0000:06:00.3: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.612332] jmb38x_ms 0000:06:00.3: setting latency timer to 64
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.699170] PM: resume of drv:uvcvideo dev:2-4:1.0 complete after 101.965 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.699179] PM: resume of drv:uvcvideo dev:2-4:1.1 complete after 101.932 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.699186] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_00 complete after 101.917 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.699197] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_83 complete after 101.972 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.716148] PM: resume of drv:hub dev:3-0:1.0 complete after 119.543 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.716155] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_00 complete after 119.544 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.716161] PM: resume of drv:hub dev:5-0:1.0 complete after 119.420 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.716168] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_00 complete after 119.381 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.716174] PM: resume of drv:hub dev:8-0:1.0 complete after 119.141 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.716181] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_00 complete after 119.104 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.716186] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_81 complete after 119.579 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.716191] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_81 complete after 119.427 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.716197] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_81 complete after 119.143 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.747148] firewire_core: skipped bus generations, destroying all nodes
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.776093] PM: resume of drv:hp_accel dev:HPQ0004:00 complete after 167.225 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.777243] i8042 kbd 00:08: wake-up capability disabled by ACPI
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.777278] ene_ir 00:0a: wake-up capability disabled by ACPI
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.820100] PM: resume of drv:hub dev:4-0:1.0 complete after 223.436 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.820115] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_00 complete after 223.444 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.820123] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_81 complete after 223.456 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.820206] PM: resume of drv:hub dev:7-0:1.0 complete after 223.266 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.820221] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_81 complete after 223.260 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.820238] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_00 complete after 223.255 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.820295] PM: resume of drv:hub dev:6-0:1.0 complete after 223.453 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.820302] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_00 complete after 223.415 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.820321] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_81 complete after 223.457 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2225.932108] usb 4-2: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.086714] PM: resume of drv:usbhid dev:4-2:1.0 complete after 489.393 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.086728] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_81 complete after 489.384 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.086745] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_00 complete after 489.329 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.086753] PM: resume of drv:usbhid dev:4-2:1.1 complete after 489.384 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.086764] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_82 complete after 489.373 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.180555] usb 7-2: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.244858] firewire_core: rediscovered device fw0
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.335066] btusb 7-2:1.0: no reset_resume for driver btusb?
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.335068] btusb 7-2:1.1: no reset_resume for driver btusb?
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.432082] usb 6-1: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.578280] PM: resume of drv:nvidia dev:0000:01:00.0 complete after 985.301 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.584296] PM: resume of drv:usb dev:7-2:1.0 complete after 986.693 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.584308] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_00 complete after 986.452 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.584311] PM: resume of drv:usb dev:7-2:1.1 complete after 986.616 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.584315] PM: resume of drv:usb dev:7-2:1.3 complete after 986.483 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.584320] PM: resume of drv:usb dev:7-2:1.2 complete after 986.556 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.584328] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_03 complete after 986.588 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.584331] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_81 complete after 986.704 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.584334] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_83 complete after 986.617 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.584337] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_82 complete after 986.688 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.584340] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_02 complete after 986.667 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.584344] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_84 complete after 986.558 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.584352] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_04 complete after 986.542 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.590883] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_00 complete after 993.327 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.590887] PM: resume of drv:usb dev:6-1:1.0 complete after 993.424 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.590927] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_82 complete after 993.395 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.590934] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_81 complete after 993.426 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.590940] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_01 complete after 993.456 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.592450] PM: resume of drv:sd dev:0:0:0:0 complete after 995.343 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.592461] PM: resume of drv:scsi_disk dev:0:0:0:0 complete after 802.688 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.592472] PM: resume of drv:scsi_device dev:0:0:0:0 complete after 995.324 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.600339] PM: resume of devices complete after 1008.129 msecs
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.601293] PM: resume devices took 1.008 seconds
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.601330] PM: Finishing wakeup.
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.601332] Restarting tasks ... done.
Jun  1 10:42:21 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2226.625660] video LNXVIDEO:01: Restoring backlight state
Jun  1 10:42:22 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2227.478921] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
Jun  1 10:42:22 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2227.481981] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
Jun  1 10:42:22 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2227.527727] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Jun  1 10:42:22 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2227.532468] r8169 0000:03:00.0: eth0: link down
Jun  1 10:42:22 igor-laptop kernel: [ 2227.533967] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
```

pm_suspend.log:

```
Fri Jun  1 10:42:14 MSK 2012: Running hooks for suspend.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change suspend suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging suspend suspend:
Linux igor-laptop 3.2.0-25-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 23 20:33:05 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
Module                  Size  Used by
pci_stub               12550  1 
vboxpci                22882  0 
vboxnetadp             13328  0 
vboxnetflt             27211  0 
vboxdrv               252189  3 vboxpci,vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt
dm_crypt               22528  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     31775  1 
snd_hda_codec_idt      60251  1 
arc4                   12473  2 
hp_wmi                 13652  0 
sparse_keymap          13658  1 hp_wmi
rfcomm                 38139  12 
snd_hda_intel          32765  5 
snd_hda_codec         109562  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13276  1 snd_hda_codec
bnep                   17830  2 
btusb                  17912  2 
bluetooth             158438  23 rfcomm,bnep,btusb
joydev                 17393  0 
parport_pc             32114  0 
snd_pcm                80845  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
ppdev                  12849  0 
uvcvideo               67203  0 
binfmt_misc            17292  1 
videodev               86588  1 uvcvideo
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_rawmidi            25424  1 snd_seq_midi
nvidia              10958194  43 
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                51567  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
ir_lirc_codec          12739  0 
lirc_dev               18700  1 ir_lirc_codec
snd_timer              28931  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14172  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
ir_mce_kbd_decoder     12681  0 
ir_sony_decoder        12462  0 
ir_jvc_decoder         12459  0 
ir_rc6_decoder         12459  0 
psmouse                87213  0 
ir_rc5_decoder         12459  0 
serio_raw              13027  0 
iwlwifi               287934  0 
rc_rc6_mce             12454  0 
ir_nec_decoder         12459  0 
ene_ir                 18019  0 
rc_core                21263  10 ir_lirc_codec,ir_mce_kbd_decoder,ir_sony_decoder,ir_jvc_decoder,ir_rc6_decoder,ir_rc5_decoder,rc_rc6_mce,ir_nec_decoder,ene_ir
mac80211              436455  1 iwlwifi
snd                    62064  19 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
cfg80211              178679  2 iwlwifi,mac80211
hp_accel               25728  0 
lis3lv02d              19268  1 hp_accel
input_polldev          13648  1 lis3lv02d
mac_hid                13077  0 
wmi                    18744  1 hp_wmi
jmb38x_ms              17406  0 
soundcore              14635  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         14115  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
memstick               15857  1 jmb38x_ms
firewire_sbp2          18346  0 
lp                     17455  0 
parport                40930  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
vesafb                 13516  1 
usbhid                 41906  0 
hid                    77367  1 usbhid
firewire_ohci          40180  0 
firewire_core          56906  2 firewire_sbp2,firewire_ohci
crc_itu_t              12627  1 firewire_core
sdhci_pci              18324  0 
sdhci                  28241  1 sdhci_pci
r8169                  56321  0 
video                  19068  0 
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       3095544    2364260     731284          0     159020    1280240
-/+ buffers/cache:     925000    2170544
Swap:      1718916          0    1718916

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave suspend suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/01PulseAudio suspend suspend:
Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> >>> Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> >>> Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> >>> 
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/01PulseAudio suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common suspend suspend:

/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate suspend suspend:

/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/55NetworkManager suspend suspend:
Having NetworkManager put all interaces to sleep...Failed.

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/55NetworkManager suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant suspend suspend:
Failed to connect to wpa_supplicant - wpa_ctrl_open: No such file or directory

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules suspend suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock suspend suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock suspend suspend: not applicable.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq suspend suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron suspend suspend:
stop: Unknown instance: 

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm suspend suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm suspend suspend: not applicable.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led suspend suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led suspend suspend: not applicable.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend:
nVidia binary video drive detected, not using quirks.

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend:
kernel.acpi_video_flags = 0

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend suspend suspend:

/etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend suspend suspend: success.
Fri Jun  1 10:42:19 MSK 2012: performing suspend
Fri Jun  1 10:42:21 MSK 2012: Awake.
Fri Jun  1 10:42:21 MSK 2012: Running hooks for resume
Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend resume suspend:

/etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend resume suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video resume suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video resume suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler resume suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler resume suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led resume suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led resume suspend: not applicable.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm resume suspend:

/dev/sda:
 setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
 APM_level  = 254

/dev/sda:
 setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
 APM_level  = 254

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm resume suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron resume suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron resume suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq resume suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq resume suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock resume suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock resume suspend: not applicable.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules resume suspend:
Reloaded unloaded modules.

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules resume suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant resume suspend:
Failed to connect to wpa_supplicant - wpa_ctrl_open: No such file or directory

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant resume suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/55NetworkManager resume suspend:
Having NetworkManager wake interfaces back up...Failed.

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/55NetworkManager resume suspend: success.
Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate resume suspend:

/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate resume suspend: success.
Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common resume suspend:

/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common resume suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/01PulseAudio resume suspend:
Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> >>> Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> >>> Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> >>> 
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/01PulseAudio resume suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave resume suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave resume suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging resume suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging resume suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume suspend: success.
Fri Jun  1 10:42:22 MSK 2012: Finished.
```

Comment: This problem affects many people, also appears in Debian, and in stable versions up until UBuntu where I just had it.14.04. Sure sometimes questions here might be pointing toi bugs in software, or missing features, perfect software wouldn't have many of the problems asked for here, or would solve it automatically, but still its a database of helpful hints and workarounds.

Comment: Also re-appeared in http://askubuntu.com/questions/449871/laptop-fails-to-suspend-or-hibernate-wakes-up-after-2-5-seconds-without-user-in

Answer (score 20):

On the HP Envy dv6, the following works on 13.10 (after upgrade from 13.04; 13.04 had no  suspend issues) using acpitool(1).

1. use `acpitool -w` to list wakeup capable devices.

> Device S-state   Status   Sysfs node
>
> ```
>   ---------------------------------------
>   1. P0P1   S4    *disabled
>   2. KBD0   S3    *enabled   pnp:00:07
>   3. PS2M   S3    *disabled  pnp:00:08
>   4. EHC1   S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
>   5. EHC2   S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.0
>   6. XHC    S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
> ```
>
> etc

The USB devices are 4,5,6. How do I know? I compared the sysfs node values to the output of `lspci|grep USB`

1. Use `acpitool -W` to disable the USB devices:

> acpitool -W 4; acpitool -W 5; acpitool -W 6

Comment: This helped me (note: number in "acpitool -W NUMBER" should be changed according to listing genereted by "acpitool -w"), so +1.
 Btw: i was only affected when i turned computer on **WITH PLUGGED**  USB HDD. If i turned on computer **WITHOUT PLUGGED** USB HDD and after a while i plugged in - all worked CORRECTLY. O_o

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 14.04, Thinkpad T431s, too! After reading this, I suspect the root cause might be the external Backup HDD - wil check if the occurence of the thing is bound to it's use. 

Shell command to save me from figuring out stuff manually:

`acpitool -w| grep enabled | grep -v LID| cut -d. -f1 | xargs -n 1 sudo acpitool -W`

Comment: How can I make this permanent?

Comment: Great; for me it was the Ethernet controller which resumed, disabling it solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

The [similar problem](http://www.ubuntu-es.org/node/167890) with awake immediately after suspend exists on ASUS Eeepc 1201n:

The solution posted there suggests adding two commands to the `/etc/rc.local` file:

> The solution I have found is very simple and effective. The only problem that makes the laptop wake up are two USB components that need to be disabled. To do that edit the file `/etc/rc.local`:

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

> It should look like this:

```sh
 #!/bin/sh-e
 # Rc.local
 # This script is Executed at the End of Each multiuser runlevel.
 # Make sure the script That will "exit 0" on success or Any Other
 # Value on error.
 #
 # In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
 # Bits.
 #
 # By default this script does nothing.
 
 # Added by Carlos TD
 
 echo US15 | sudo tee /proc/acpi/wakeup
 echo USB0 | sudo tee /proc/acpi/wakeup
 
 exit 0
```

> All I did was add these two commands:

```
echo US15 | sudo tee /proc/acpi/wakeup
echo USB0 | sudo tee /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

> These orders are for USB components that did not allow the laptop to remain suspended. Disabling it from the local file does not affect the system
>
> If you want to see all the USB components enabled to wake the laptop, this is the command. You will notice that these two are no
> longer enabled (of course after reboot):

```
cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

> This very good and simple solution I found this forum, and then adapted it to my eeepc. I think it is for many laptops with this
> problem. You only need to adapt the trick to each machine by testing out which USB devices are the problem. You can test by running the above mentioned command for each device and testing sleep functionality.
> I found it on this forum: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1969615

Answer (score 3):

On my Asus 1201N, adding only

```
echo US15 | sudo tee /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

to `/etc/rc.local` fixed the problem with suspend.