# laptop fails to suspend or hibernate (wakes up after 2-5 seconds without user interaction)

Tags: laptop, suspend, hibernate, thinkpad, wakeup

This all started happening after upgrading to 13.10, now I am running 14.04 and still have the same issue.

When I close the lid or I do `sudo pm-suspend` the laptop goes into suspend for 2-5 seconds and awakes by itself.

Same happens if I try to do hibernate.

I have a gut feeling that something is awaking/taking the cpu out of suspend mode but I cannot figure out what.

Any help troubleshooting this annoying issue?

Edit:

Thanks to @Fabian , I was able to figure out that it looks like the ethernet card is misbehaving and even after I set the card to not wake up on lan (either doing `acpitool -W 3` or `echo disabled > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:19.0/power/wakeup` or `echo IGBE > /proc/acpi/wakeup`, the laptop keeps waking up and showing this when I do `acpitool -w`

```
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
---------------------------------------
1. LID    S3    *enabled 
2. SLPB   S3    *disabled
3. IGBE   S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:19.0
4. EXP1   S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.0
5. EXP2   S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.1
6. EXP3   S4    *disabled
7. EXP4   S4    *disabled
8. EXP5   S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.4
9. EHC1   S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.0
10. EHC2      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1a.0
11. HDEF      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1b.0
```

Any idea how to proceed from there?

The network driver that IGBE uses is `e1000e`

Comment: use `dmesg` to see the latest messages from the kernel, something there could give you a clue as to what's happening.

Comment: Have you disabled the Wake-On-Lan feature in the BIOS?

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I tried.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have kernel 13.13 and Intel Z77X based motherboard, and following command works for me:

```
sudo sh -c "echo EHC1 > /proc/acpi/wakeup;echo EHC2 > /proc/acpi/wakeup;echo XHC > /proc/acpi/wakeup"
```

Answer (score 12):

The following worked for me:

```
cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

Look for any items with status enabled that look like they don't belong there (for me, anything except LID0). Then disable them by saying, for example:

```
sudo sh -c "echo XHC0 > /proc/acpi/wakeup"
```

Check that the corresponding entries have indeed been disabled, send the laptop into suspend and hope for the best :)

Comment: Very good lead, now I need to find out why the integrated ethernet card keeps waking up even though I set the wake up mode for it to disabled

Comment: Good luck with that :)

Comment: Have you tried `rmmod` the driver before suspending? (Just a shot in the dark)

Comment: Same annoying problem in Ubuntu 16.04.1. This answer didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: +1 This is the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Experiencing exactly the same problem (ThinkPad T530, Ubuntu 14.04, but also 13.10 and 13.04, after couple of suspends, computer resumes immediately after suspend).

Disabling IBGE from wakeup did not help at all.

As suggested by Romano, I've tried removing the e1000e module, et voila suspend as expected.

So:

```
sudo rmmod e1000e
```

prior to suspend resolves the issue.

Interestingly, the problem reappears immediately after installing the module back (`sudo modprobe e1000e`) and suspending without its removal. So, it must've been something related to hardware.

To automate it, I've created two simple suspend/wakeup scripts (tested on the above mentioned hardware, Ubuntu Trusty 14.04): `sudo gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/99_e1000e_remove` :

```
#!/bin/sh

# Remove e1000e kernel module prior to suspend
rmmod e1000e
```

and
`sudo gedit /etc/pm/power.d/99_e1000e_probe` :

```
#!/bin/sh

# Modprobe e1000e kernel module after resume
modprobe e1000e
```

Scripts should be executable (`sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/99_e1000e_remove /etc/pm/power.d/99_e1000e_probe`).

Notes:

- I assume the scripts are pretty safe to use even when it does not
  address your problem.
- I'm not using LAN wakeup, so I don't know how
  it behaves with the fix.

Comment: The laptop has the same issue using windows (I just installed windows 7 for my wife in the computer because I got a new one) and it does exactly the same. So it may be hardware/firmware related

Comment: Hi. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with a Thinkpad X201s. This solution removing e1000e with the little helper scripts helped getting suspend to work again.

Thank you very much !

Comment: I can confirm the same solution works on a Thinkpad T540p and Ubuntu 14.04. Something seems to go wrong inside the `e1000e` module. This only happens occasionally to begin with, most of the time suspending works well. If the problem appears, I `rmmod e1000e`, then I can suspend successfully. However, if I then `modprobe` it again after resuming, the next suspend will work even with the module present. So "resetting" the `e1000e` module appears to do the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (taken from another thread on askubuntu):

[Ubuntu 14.04 wake up immediately after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/479254/ubuntu-14-04-wake-up-immediately-after-suspend)

> You can try to disable it with a [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) script every startup
>   automatically:
>
> Create a file `etc/init/disable-XHC.conf`
>
> Content:
>
> ```
> start on started dbus
> stop on stopping dbus
>
> script
>    sudo -u root sh -c "echo 'XHC' > /proc/acpi/wakeup"
> end script
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The systemd solution is to create an instruction for systemd-tmpfiles to write something to a file when it is invoked.

Create a file in `/etc/tmpfiles.d`, e.g. `/etc/tmpfiles.d/disable-network-wake.conf`, with the following content, depending on what device you want to disable wakeup for.

```
w /proc/acpi/wakeup - - - - XHC
```

See also systemd-tmpfiles(8) and tmpfiles.d(5).

Ref: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Temporary_files