# Sleep mode problem

Tags: power-management, suspend

I've jumped the ship and I am sinking into dark waters of Linux..  :-) Hopefully to see bright future. 
I need some assistance or guidance as I am new to linux. I have installed Latest version of Ubuntu on my Aspire S7-392. I had some issues with "fake" raid so I've got rid off it and I was able to install Ubuntu. 
 I have one major issue that is important to me and that is laptop not going into suspend mode when powered from battery causing complete discharge when lid is closed.

When I try to suspend it with the lid opened to see what is happening I can see screen going black, then flicker and back to login screen immidiatelly.

```
  Can you help me to fix this issue?  Thanks  Charles
```

---

It's working now. Not really sure why but it is...

Comment: [Sounds like a similar issue as this user.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449871/laptop-fails-to-suspend-or-hibernate-wakes-up-after-2-5-seconds-without-user-in)

Edit: Formatting.

Comment: Please copy your `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` and your `/var/log/syslog` to http://paste.ubuntu.com and add the links to your question.

Comment: Here is pm-suspend.log link [link] (http://paste.ubuntu.com/7442117/)

Comment: And here is syslog link http://paste.ubuntu.com/7442183/