# Ubuntu 14.04 wake up immediately after suspend

Tags: 14.04, suspend

My laptop is Toshiba M840. When I suspend, my laptop auto resumes immediately. I used `acpitool` to check what devices made my computer waking up. After I disable the XHC, my computer suspends properly. But after restart, the XHC was enabled. 
How can I disable it forever?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to disable it with a [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) script every startup automatically:

Create a file `etc/init/disable-XHC.conf`

Content:

```
start on started dbus
stop on stopping dbus

script
   sudo -u root sh -c "echo 'XHC' > /proc/acpi/wakeup"
end script
```