# how to make hibernate work on 14.04?

Tags: power-management, hibernate, pm-utils

My Ubuntu is 14.04 on Thinkpad T400.

I try to run the following command for hibernation:

```
sudo pm-hibernate
```

It flashes and then return back to normal. Running `pm-suspend-hybrid`
    also flashes and return back to normal. only `sudo pm-suspend` will work. How shall I hibernate then?

`pm-is-supported --hibernate` and `pm-is-supported --suspend-hybrid`
don't return anything, which I assumes to mean my system supports
both?

Does the output of `pm-is-supported` also imply BIOS allow all sleep modes?

---

Here is the output of `/proc/acpi/wakeup`.

```
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
LID   S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0D:00
SLPB      S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0E:00
UART      S3    *disabled
IGBE      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:19.0
EXP0      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.0
EXP1      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.1
EXP2      S4    *disabled
EXP3      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.3
EXP4      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.4
PCI1      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1e.0
USB0      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
USB3      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.0
USB5      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.2
EHC0      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.7
EHC1      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.7
HDEF      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1b.0
```

1. Does the wakeup file apply equally to both suspend and hibernate? If yes, then does your method solve the problem for hibernate, given that I can suspend but can't hibernate?
2. Do "enabled" and "disabled" mean if the device can or cannot wake up the OS?
3. how shall I try to change the wakeup file to see if it makes hibernate possible?

Comment: Do you have a swap partition on your hard drive/SSD?

Comment: Yes, twice of my RAM.

Comment: See here,  maybe helpful: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/fix-for-suspend-and-hibernation-problem-for-laptops.html

Comment: Found this [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449871/laptop-fails-to-suspend-or-hibernate-wakes-up-after-2-5-seconds-without-user-in). Might be helpful, too

Comment: What's the content of `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` just after a failed hibernation attempt?

Answer (score 1):

Some device is waking up your machine immediately.

You can show all devices which can wakeup and those states with `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup`

```
# cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
PS2K      S4    *disabled
PS2M      S4    *disabled
UAR1      S4    *disabled  pnp:00:06
P0P1      S4    *disabled
RP01      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP02      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP03      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP04      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP07      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.6
PXSX      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:06:00.0
RP08      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
PEG0      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:01.0
PEGP      S4    *disabled
PEG1      S4    *disabled
PEG2      S4    *disabled
PEG3      S4    *disabled
RP05      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.4
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:03:00.0
RP06      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.5
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:04:00.0
GLAN      S4    *disabled
EHC1      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.0
EHC2      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1a.0
XHC   S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:14.0
HDEF      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1b.0
PWRB      S4    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0C:00
```

In my case it turned out that USB (`EHC1` and `EHC2`) was responsible for the wakeup. You can toggle each device with `echo <DEVICE> | sudo tee /proc/acpi/wakeup` where `<DEVICE>` is the device name from the list above.

Try to disable all but `PWRB` and `PXSX` and check if this helps. If so you can re-enable one after an other until you found the device which is waking up.

## EDIT

---

copy this script into gedit

```
#!/bin/sh
#Prevent USB and Ethernet from waking up
for i in "IGBE" "USB0" "USB3" "USB5" "EHC0" "EHC1"; do
echo $i | sudo tee /proc/acpi/wakeup
done
```

save it to `~/prev_wakeup` and then run `chmod 755 ~/prev_wakeup` and `~/prev_wakeup`. Next try to go into hibernate and check if this helped.

If so you can add this to your `/etc/rc.local`

```
#Prevent USB and Ethernet from waking up
for i in "IGBE" "USB0" "USB3" "USB5" "EHC0" "EHC1"; do
echo $i > /proc/acpi/wakeup
done
```

Comment: Thanks. (1)Does the wakeup file apply equally to both suspend and hibernate? If yes, then does your method solve the problem for hibernate, given that  I can suspend but can't hibernate? (2) I don't have PWRB and PXSX in the wakeup file. (see my edit to my post) (3) Do "enabled"  and  "disabled" mean  if the device can or cannot wake up the OS?

Comment: (1)AFAIK it apply for both suspend and hibernate. Didn't recognize suspend is working for you. (2)You have LID (closing the lid) SLPB (sleep button) which should be kept enabled (3)correct

Answer (score 0):

- If you don't have a `swap partition` create one.
     By using any gparted(for linux) or any aomei/mini partition tools for windows(if you're dual booting).
- Make that partition in `ext2` file system.
- After creating the partition you have to format it.
- Before formatting we shall know it's label like sda1 or sda2 etc. for this type in terminal **`sudo blkid`** or **`sudo lsblk`**. It gives UUID and type of partition.
- After knowing the partition type
      **`sudo mkswap /dev/sdxx`** this formats the partition.
- Then you have to mount the partition by
      **`sudo swapon -U UUID`**
- Then open **`gedit /etc/fstab`** and add this line to that file-
     `UUID=XXX none swap sw 0 0`
- If you want to use your swap for hibernating then you need to update the UUID in 
     **`/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`** with this content **`RESUME=UUID=xxx`**.
     Don't forget to **`sudo update-initramfs -u`**

---

***To enable hibernate option in power menu***-

- `sudo gedit /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`
- Type in it-

  > [Re-enable hibernate by default in upower] 
  >       Identity=unix-user:* 
  >       Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate 
  >       ResultActive=yes
  >       [Re-enable hibernate by default in logind] 
  >       Identity=unix-user:* 
  >       Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate 
  >       ResultActive=yes
- Type `sudo killall unity-panel-service`
- Hibernate option enabled in power menu

Comment: following your answer, I have cryptswap1 in fstab, ive also noted after i entry my pass phrase on boot up i get a notice to wait or skip while swap is mounted which i do wait. should i change /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 to the uuid or leave it as is?

Comment: This may help you [link]http://askubuntu.com/questions/341979/what-to-do-about-the-disk-drive-for-dev-mapper-cryptswap1-is-not-ready-yet-or

Comment: Thank you for the link, i couldnt follow those pages as for some reason there wasnt a separate swap partition. As it was a fresh install bar for some emails that were still on the mail server I have reinstalled without encrytion, hopefully i will get to the bottom of my lack of hibernation now. Thanks again.