# Ubuntu 14.04 wakes up immediately after suspend or shut down after network card firmware update

Tags: 14.04, suspend, power-management, shutdown

I know there are many topics regarding the problem of ubuntu waking up immediately after suspend/hibbernate/shut down. Unfortunately I have not found anything that helped my case.

First of all my specs:

```
Vendor: Hewlett-Packard
Version: 68IRR Ver. F.31
Release Date: 08/31/2012
Address: 0xF0000
Runtime Size: 64 kB
ROM Size: 5120 kB
Characteristics:
    PCI is supported
    PC Card (PCMCIA) is supported
    BIOS is upgradeable
    BIOS shadowing is allowed
    Boot from CD is supported
    Selectable boot is supported
    EDD is supported
    Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
    8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
    Serial services are supported (int 14h)
    Printer services are supported (int 17h)
    ACPI is supported
    USB legacy is supported
    Smart battery is supported
    BIOS boot specification is supported
    Function key-initiated network boot is supported
    Targeted content distribution is supported
    UEFI is supported
BIOS Revision: 15.49
Firmware Revision: 88.29
System Information
    Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
    Product Name: HP ProBook 4540s
    Version: A1018C1100
    Serial Number: 2CE2380P1K
    UUID: FF4A5332-0181-11E2-B432-E088B300800F
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: C4Y89EA#ACB
    Family: 103C_5336AN G=N L=BUS B=HP S=PRO
```

I tried so far this:

[no IGBE, so did not move on to the workaround of e1000e](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449871/laptop-fails-to-suspend-or-hibernate-wakes-up-after-2-5-seconds-without-user-in)

[similiar to the link prior](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598236/ubuntu-wakes-up-after-few-seconds-of-sleep)

[known issue with xhci module](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/522998)

I do have the feeling, that this:

[might help](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-fix-computer-keeps-waking.htm) but I do not know on how to walk this through on ubuntu.

If someone could help, I would be very thankful.

Cheers,

Martin